# Kubuntu 23 wont boot after update, kernel panic?

Tags: boot, kernel

I have Kubuntu 23 running on dell xps 15, it won't boot after update? , how do I fix it?

[The screen photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RML1Z.jpg)

Comment: Try to boot a previous kernel from the grub loader menu. If does not appear during boot press `Esc`

Comment: Worked,  thank you.